# Android Canvas OpenGL Renderer is out of memory

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-view

I develop android library for drawing chart at view, using canvas.
However, the following errors occur frequently.

LogCat:

```
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(11526): NvRmChannelSubmit: NvError_IoctlFailed with error code 12
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(11526): NvRmChannelSubmit failed (err = 196623, SyncPointValue = 94008102)
(87 times repeat)
D/OpenGLRenderer(11526): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x505
E/OpenGLRenderer(11526): OpenGLRenderer is out of memory!
```

Solution is not found although I am groping for various causes and solution. 
So, please tell me about what can become a cause which such an error generates?
And how can solve this problem.

I beg your kindness. Finally my sincere apologies for my poor English.

Comment: hard to tell. What exactly are you doing? Do you use big textures or so? Maybe this would be a quick fix for that problem. Which Version of OpenGL do you use? GlES 2.0 or GL1.0?

Comment: Just use SKIA http://code.google.com/p/skia/ , it's much more appropriate for what you want to do and drain a less number of resources, using a pure OpenGL context to just visualize some docs it's highly discouraged.

Comment: As a temporary fix, change to the system drawing from OpenL, work it. But have draw many times repeated...(reference from 2ch<Japanese> http://toro.2ch.net/test/read.cgi/tech/1343141095/356-360)

Comment: Have you found a resolution for this? I'm getting the same error but it's localized to only my Asus Transformer.